# SQLAlchemy sqlite create_engine throws an exception

Tags: sqlalchemy

I use an sqlite db for my unittests and tried to update to the 2.0.4 version of SQLAlchemy recently and this leads to an issue with creating a test sqlite DB:

```
    engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://')
    sqlalchemy_connection = engine.connect()
```

```
dbapi_connection = <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7f9ea0ba6570>

    def set_regexp(dbapi_connection):
>       dbapi_connection.create_function(
            "regexp", 2, regexp, **create_func_kw
        )
E       TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Works fine with 1.4.16, anyone got any ideas? (the create_engine semms to be at fault, but looks similar to the examples in the migration guide)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an incompatibility issue of a quite old sqlite version (shipped with rhel 7 for example) and sqlalchemy 2.0, for the complete discussion, see: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9379